# How to give reference to a row number in excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiplication

I need this formula: C(n) = B(n)*A5. (n is the row number)

Literally, multiply the current selected row number in column B with A5

I tried =ROW function for creating a reference but failed.

I tried with this formula: `C(2) =MULTIPLY(B=ROW(),A5)` thinking it will be parsed to  `C(2) =MULTIPLY(B2,A5)`

Answer (score 9):

You have two options to accomplish this:

**1. INDEX() formula:**

```
=INDEX(B:B,ROW())*A5
```

**2. INDIRECT() formula:**

```
=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())*A5
```

Where `ROW()` is the number of cell you're entering this formula into.

Comment: what is the purpose of : operator?

Comment: It means a range of cells. `B1:B5` - all 5 cells. `B:B` - the whole `B` column. `1:1` - the whole row `1`.

Comment: 3rd option: `=Offset(B1,ROW()-1)*$A$5` :)

Answer (score 2):

Found it.

`=MULTIPLY(INDIRECT("F" & ROW()),INDIRECT(("G" & 2)))`

`INDIRECT(("G" & 2))` even makes it better if you want to drag and copy the functionality to all the rows below.

Comment: `=MULTIPLY(...` is not an Excel worksheet function. You may be interested in the [PRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PRODUCT-function-8E6B5B24-90EE-4650-AEEC-80982A0512CE).

Comment: `INDIRECT()` should be used with caution as it's the Excel's equivalent of `eval()` - it uses strings as parameters so the formulas will not adjust references if you copy them to other cells, it will be slower on large scales calculation etc.

Comment: I haven't worked out what's wrong with =F2*$G$2 copied down?